# Unable to import grafana json file via the grafana helm chart

Tags: grafana, kubernetes-helm

I am deploying the helm chart stable/grafana 4.3.0 onto a k8s cluster. I am using Helm 3. From a previous grafana installation, I have exported the json of a dashboard and saved it as my-dashboard.json. I want to have helm take care of uploading this file, so in my values.yaml I have

```
dashboardProviders:
 dashboardproviders.yaml:
   apiVersion: 1
   providers:
   - name: 'default'
     orgId: 1
     folder: ''
     type: file
     disableDeletion: false
     editable: true
     options:
       path: /var/lib/grafana/dashboards
dashboards:
  default:
    my-dashboard:
      file: my-dashboard.json
    prometheus-stats:
      gnetId: 2
      revision: 2
      datasource: Prometheus
```

I already have my Prometheus datasource (from the prometheus helm chart) defined as

```
datasources:
 datasources.yaml:
   apiVersion: 1
   datasources:
   - name: Prometheus
     type: prometheus
     url: http://my-prometheus-release-server.default.svc.cluster.local
     access: proxy
     isDefault: true
```

And I've verified that the datasource works correctly.

If I run `helm upgrade my-grafana-release stable/grafana --values values.yaml` however, in the logs on the pod it repeats:

`t=2020-01-17T21:33:35+0000 lvl=eror msg="failed to load dashboard from " logger=provisioning.dashboard type=file name=default file=/var/lib/grafana/dashboards/default/my-dashboard.json error=EOF`

Seeing `EOF` makes me think the file isn't uploading. I have my-dashboard.json saved in the same folder as values.yaml, and I'm running the helm command from that folder. Do I need to store it somewhere else? I have searched all the documentation and it's not clear to me how it gets uploaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found another way to handle this.

I am using Terraform to accomplish this, and I made values.yaml as a template file. This is the relevant section in values.yaml now:

```
dashboards:
  default:
    dashbaord1:
      json: |
        ${my-dashboard-1}
    dashboard2:
      json: |
        ${my-dashboard-2}
```

And the templatefile block looks like this:

```
resource "helm_release" "grafana" {
  name       = "grafana-release"
  repository = data.helm_repository.stable.metadata[0].name
  chart      = "grafana"
  version    = "4.3.0"

  values = [
    "${templatefile(
      "${path.module}/values.yaml.tpl",
      {
        my-dashboard-1         = "${indent(8, data.template_file.my-dashboard-1.rendered)}}",
        my-dashboard-2 = "${indent(8, data.template_file.my-dashboard-2.rendered)}}"
      }
    )}"
  ]
}
```

The `indent` is very important!

Answer (score 3):

For anyone stumbling on this:
In case you installed grafana with the grafana helm chart or prometheus operator helm chart an easy way to add grafana dashboards is to set `sidecar.dashboards.enabled: true` in your values.yml (I recommend checking the docs for more info on this).

Then you can add dashboards with a simple configmap like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: my-grafana-dashboard
  labels:
     grafana_dashboard: "1"
data:
  my-dashboard.json: |
    {
        "annotations": {
        "list": [
            {
       .....JSON.....
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Where did you put the `my-dashboard.json`file ?
It should be on the same level as `values.yaml`
Also check the `grafana-dashboards-default` configmap, it should contain the dashboard.

Comment: It was on the same level as values.yaml. After reading more closely and looking at the chart source code, it looks like it actually needs to be in the *chart* repository level. I have found another way to handle this.